# Jquery cycle scrubber plugin: adding links to images

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink, cycle

I'm using this jquery plugin which lets you scrub through images:
http://thespiral.ca/jquery/scrubber/demo/

I'm trying to add a link to each image, like this for example:

```
<div id="basic">
<a href="google.com"><img src="images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach1" /></a>
<a href="yahoo.com"><img src="images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach2" /></a>
<a href="bbc.com"><img src="images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach3" /></a></div>
```

But something in the script seems to be blocking links, and no matter what I do the image have a "#" link.

Can anyone help?

Update:
I put up a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qdGXZ/

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "blocking links"? Can you post the javascript you are using as well? (double bonus points if you add the javascript to this page AND put up a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net))

Comment: Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qdGXZ/ .By "blocking links" I mean something in the script seems to be overriding any hyperlink I try to use for the images with "#"

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in `jquery.cycle.all.min.js`. There is a code in it that may cause this kind of behaviour. Here it is:

```
else{a='<a href="#">'+(i+1)+"</a>";}
```

Comment it and see what happens. This was the only piece of code in the given example that could cause this. 
To fix this you need to pass href attribute defined by you to the else case and do something like this:

```
else{a='<a href="'+el.attr("href")+'">'+(i+1)+"</a>";}
```

I don't know if this will help. Just can't do much. Now you know what is the problem and what you should do to fix it. The rest is up to you.

Comment: ok, I tried to do that, and it caused the scrubbing to stop working, though the link does work: http://briefeditions.com/coop/tests/scrubbertest.html